# ClearCase 8 works with Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, clearcase

VS 2005 is no longer supported by MS, but I still have to use it on a ClearCase client v8.

VS 2005 is not mentioned on IBM website as a supported version for ClearCase 8. However I'm wondering if CC8 supports Visual Studio add-in? i.e. be able to checkin/checkout directly from Visual Studio IDE

Have you tried them both together?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM ClearCase requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036569) for the [software part](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=1316006977787) mentions:

Microsoft Visual Studio

- 2010 (8.0.1+)
- 2012 (8.0.1+)
- 2013 (8.0.1.2 2013 and future fix packs, 8.0.1.3)

So VS2005 is not supported (and I don't know of a third-part plugin which would be compatible to CC8 for VS2005).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know IBM does not mention it. I have to change the question. Actually I'm wondering if someone uses them both together although it is officially not supported.

Comment: @user1762109 I understand that. I am not aware of any plugin for VS 2005 supporting CC8.

Comment: Do you know if that's possible to install ClearCase Add-in for Visual Studio if ClearCase is already installed?
I'd like to try to connect VS2005 add-in to ClearCase 8 and I know that ClearCase' installation manager will not offer to install VS2005... Thank you

Comment: @user1762109 that would be because VS2005 isn't supported by CC8+

Comment: do you know if there's a work-around to activate CC add-in on VS?

Comment: @user1762109 no I do not: as far as I know, VS2005 is a bit too old for the recent CC8+